What is the velocity anisotropy in galaxies?
I came across this term recenlty, and it seems that there aren't many sites explaining it well.
What is galaxy anisotropy velocity?

It would help if you gave a link to where you came across the term, since the meaning may depend on context.

You should not cross-post questions on >1 stack exchange. You have asked this question on Astronomy SE.  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/58172/what-is-galaxy-velocity-anisotropy
